# subtract between rows in pairs in dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image: the expected output of my calculation]

I have a dataframe with columns: `prime, target, condition, meanRT.`
I want to have a new column (as in the outer rightmost column): which is the difference in `meanRT` between '`strong`' prime-target pairs and '`unrel_strong`' pairs, and difference in `meanRT` between '`weak`' prime-target pairs and '`unrel_weak`' pairs, with the condition that they should have the same '`target`' words. The expected output is in my attached picture. The highlighted ones with same colors are the differences in pairs to be calculated .

My codes are as follows:

```
# this condition is to set the same 'target' words:
if data[data['condition']=='strong']['target']==data[data['condition']=='unrel_strong']['target']:
    data['diff']=data.loc[data['condition']=='strong', ['meanRT']]-data.loc[data['condition']=='unrel_strong', ['meanRT']]
if data[data['condition']=='weak']['target']==data[data['condition']=='unrel_weak']['target']:
    data['diff']=data.loc[data['condition']=='weak', ['meanRT']]-data.loc[data['condition']=='unrel_weak', ['meanRT']]
```

but the error arised from the first '`if`' condition

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

So how can I fix the code to get my expected output as in the picture as in the outer rightmost column?
I hope my question is clear enough

Answer (score 0):

Create a new column that flags a record for strong or weak label based on the condition column

```
import numpy
df['strength'] = np.where(df['condition'].str.contains('strong'), 'Strong', 'Weak')

   target     condition  meanRT strength
0  rights        strong      20   Strong
1  rights          weak      18     Weak
2  rights  unrel_strong      15   Strong
3  rights    unrel_weak      10     Weak
4    ring        strong      12   Strong
5    ring          weak       8     Weak
6    ring  unrel_strong       5   Strong
7    ring    unrel_weak       4     Weak
```

Group by target and the newly created flag to obtain the difference between meanRT

```
df['difference'] = df.groupby(['target', 'strength'])['meanRT'].transform(lambda x: x.max()-x.min())

   target     condition  meanRT strength  difference
0  rights        strong      20   Strong           5
1  rights          weak      18     Weak           8
2  rights  unrel_strong      15   Strong           5
3  rights    unrel_weak      10     Weak           8
4    ring        strong      12   Strong           7
5    ring          weak       8     Weak           4
6    ring  unrel_strong       5   Strong           7
7    ring    unrel_weak       4     Weak           4
```

Comment: Thanks, but it returned this warning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df['strength'] = np.where(df['condition'].str.contains('strong'), 'Strong', 'Weak')
  df['size_prime_effect'] = df.groupby(['target', 'strength'])['meanRT'].transform(lambda x: x.max()-x.min()). I am a bit lost at how to fix this error. Do you have any ideas to help me please?

Comment: Its not really an error, only a warning. It wont affect the flow of your code

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to run the output. Thank you. It works